# User defined unit conversion and displayUnit in Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have been working with several non-SI medical units on OpenModelica and created a package to contain them. What I wanted to do is to select another user defined unit for display purposes. This is done pretty easily for the types in Modelica library such as

```
Modelica.SIunits.Pressure P_example(displayUnit="bar");
```

To be more specific about the problem, I am working with 2 different pressure units: **cmH2O** and **mmHg**. My variables in the model are in **cmH2O**, so are all the calculations. I want to plot only few of the variables in **mmHg**. I have following declarations for the types:

```
type Pressure = Real(final quantity="Pressure", final unit="cmH2O");

type Pressure_mmHg = Real(final quantity="Pressure", final unit="mmHg");
```

As well as **to_mmHg** and **from_mmHg** functions, just like original Modelica Library. However, the variable I am trying to plot in **mmHg** still appears in **cmH2O**.

```
Types.Pressure P_lv(displayUnit="mmHg");
```

The following is working but not so fancy as I don't want to define a new variable unnecessarily.

```
Types.Pressure_mmHg P_lv_in_mmHg = Types.to_mmHg(P_lv);
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776407/teaching-modelica-medical-non-si-units